# How to requeue a message with ActiveMQ and Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I would like to know how (or if it is possible) to requeue a message with ActiveMQ and Camel. I need to requeue a message after some modifications have been made on it. 
Using `disableReplyTo=true` make the timeout error disappears, but, obviously, I don't have the result I want cause I need the reply. 
I am a bit confused with JmsReply documentation.

**EDIT:**

Here is my workflow:

```
            from(CXF_RS_ENDPOINT_URI)
                    .to("activemq:IN");

            from("activemq:IN")
                    .choice()
                        .when(header("context").isEqualTo("test")).toD("direct:${body.step}" + "_u_queue")
                        .otherwise().log("not a correct context")
                    .end();

            from("direct:" + Step.STEP1 + "_u_queue").process("step1Processor").to("activemq:IN");
            from("direct:" + Step.STEP2 + "_u_queue").process("step2Processor").to("activemq:IN");
            from("direct:" + Step.STEP3 + "_u_queue").process("step3Processor").to("mock:result");
```

Comment: you need to put more information. How are you reading from the queue?

Comment: Do you need something more?